# C++ Including header file multiple times

Tags: c++, makefile, include

I was just wondering where is it necessary/right to include a specific header file according to the example below. Let's assume I have a definition of an exception class:

```
//exc.hpp
#ifndef EXC_H
#define EXC_H
class MyException : public exception {

};
#endif /* EXC_H */
```

Then I have another class definition throwing such exception:

```
//a.cpp
void SomeClass::someMethod(void) {
  throw MyException(...);
}
```

And having another file handling that exception, e.g.:

```
//main.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

int main() {
   ...
   catch(MyException & e) { ... }
}
```

So my question is, where should I place `#include "exc.hpp"`? Just to `a.hpp`, or both `a.hpp` and `main.cpp`?

And when it comes to `makefile`... How should be the targets specified within such file?

Comment: Your "exc.hpp" is incomplete, since there is no visibility of a definition of `exception` which is used as a base class.   As such, including that header is only valid in a compilation unit that previously defines `exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every translation unit that `throw`s or `catch`es exceptions of that type will need to be able to see its definition.

Loosely speaking, that means every `.cpp` file containing a `throw` or `catch` relating to that exception must include your `.hpp` file.

That's [even if you only catch by reference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c757667dfefe6039) and never inspect the exception object, which is not the case in other areas of C++ (where a forward declaration will do).

Makefiles are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Both the file with implementation (`a.cpp`) and all files the use the class (`main.cpp`) should have the `#include`.

`a.cpp` without the include must not compile at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the .hpp file in both main.cpp and a.cpp.  The purpose of the #ifndef sequence is to prevent accidental multiple inclusion (through indirect #includes).  There is also a #pragma once directive in MS compilers that does the same thing.

The compiler figures out what .h/.hpp files to read based on the #includes in the .cpp files; the make file is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the compiler processes each source file independently, and doesn't remember anything from the source file once it's done processing.  Even if you list several source files on a single compiler command-line.

You have a header-file that defines a type.  Naturally, you must `#include` the header file in every source file where you need that type to be defined. (The compiler will not remember having seen the types when processing earlier source files.)

It might be tempting to `#include` headers within other headers, just so you don't have to `#include` so many things within the .c or .cpp files, but *this should be avoided to the degree possible*.  It produces what is known as "header coupling", and it makes code that is hard to re-use later on other projects.

There's also a fine point hiding in what I said above: "where you need that type to be defined".  There are two very specific concepts in C and C++ related to variables:

1. declaration -- when you make the compiler aware that a type exists, and
2. definition -- where you tell the compiler the details of the type.

You need to `#include` your header wherever you need the definition.  I.e., when you intend to instantiate an object of the type, define members of the type in another struct or class, or call one of its methods (assuming C++).  If instead, you only want to store a reference to objects of the type without creating or using them, a declaration will suffice, and you can just forward-declare the class.  I.e.,

```
class MyException;

void setFileNotFoundExceptionObject(const MyException *exc) { ... }
```

Many APIs are designed specifically around only using pointers or references to objects so that the API headers only need forward delcarations of the types, and not the complete definitions (This keeps the internal members of the objects hidden to prevent developers from abusing them.)

Comment: Still unclear to me... I have multiple class header definitions, however I need to include them sometimes in each other. So I end up having some *.hpp file including another *.hpp file (e.g. class B returns a pointer of object of class A). In such cases I do get a redefinition error, when I'm not using the guards. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything wrong.  *every* header uses guards. You will occasionally need to include a header in a header.